# Floating-point-to-integer conversion rounding up instead of truncating

Tags: c, floating-point, clang, ieee-754, floating-point-conversion

I was surprised to find that a floating-point-to-integer conversion rounded up instead of truncating the fractional part. Here is some sample code, compiled using Clang, that reproduces that behavior:

```
double a = 1.12;  // 1.1200000000000001 * 2^0
double b = 1024LL * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;  // 1 * 2^50
double c = a * b;  // 1.1200000000000001 * 2^50
long long d = c;  // 1261007895663739
```

Using exact math, the floating-point value represents

```
1.1200000000000001 * 2^50 = 1261007895663738.9925899906842624
```

I was expecting the resulting integer to be `1261007895663738` due to truncation but it is actually `1261007895663739`. Why?

Comment: *Using exact math* - but C does not use exact math. https://ideone.com/kG3SD4

Comment: Neither `1.12` nor `1.1200000000000001` are exact `double` values.

Comment: Assuming `double` maps to IEEE-754 `binary64`: `a=1.1200000000000001e+00  b=1.1258999068426240e+15  c=1.2610078956637390e+15  trunc(c)=1.2610078956637390e+15  floor(c)=1.2610078956637390e+15  ceil(c)=1.2610078956637390e+15  rint(c)=1.2610078956637390e+15  round(c)=1.2610078956637390e+15  d=1261007895663739`. In other words, `c` is an integer value and no information is lost in the conversion to `d`.

Comment: `double a = 1.12;  // 1.1200000000000001 * 2^0` this is wrong. The base is 10, not 2: `1.1200000000000001 * 10^0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming IEEE 754 double precision, 1.12 is exactly

```
1.12000000000000010658141036401502788066864013671875
```

Written in binary, its significand is exactly:

```
1.0001111010111000010100011110101110000101000111101100
```

Note the last two zeros are intentional, since it's what you get with double precision (1 bit before fraction separator, plus 52 fractional bits).

So, if you shift by 50 places, you'll get an integer value

```
100011110101110000101000111101011100001010001111011.00
```

or in decimal

```
1261007895663739
```

when converting to long long, no truncation/rounding occurs, the conversion is exact.

Comment: Interesting. I also noticed that if I change `double` to `long double`, the floating point number is different (more precise). Can you expand on that in your answer? Thanks!

Comment: Assuming 80-bits extented precision of x86, that is 64 bits significand, 1.12 exact value is 1.120000000000000000004336808689942017736029811203479766845703125, thus slightly smaller than the double precision... Shifted by 2^50, you get exactly '1261007895663738.8800048828125'. This one shall be truncated to 1261007895663738 when converting to long long...

Comment: Note that I'm using Squeak Smalltalk to easily obtain those values. I did not mention it in the answer, because not directly related to the C tag. But since it's same underlying floating point (as far as C adhere to IEEE 754, which it does not always), any language with convenient utilities might do the work. Smalltalk has LargeInteger (bigNum), exact Fraction, and I extended it with ArbitraryPrecisionFloat, which makes a good candidate.

Comment: Here is an example of snippet that I use `((ArbitraryPrecisionFloat readFrom: '1.12' readStream numBits: 64) timesTwoPower: 50) asFraction printShowingMaxDecimalPlaces: 100` or `1.12 significandAsInteger printStringBase: 2` etc...

Comment: I think I just don’t understand floating-point well enough. Why are the Float80 and Double numbers so different? Shouldn’t the Double number be the same as the Float80 number but with less precision?

Comment: But they are almost the same, except the last bits. When a value is not representable in base 2 (like 4/3 is represented by infinite serie of bits 1+1/2^2+1/2^4+1/2^6+1/2^8+..... that is 1.01010101010101010101010...), the infinite serie of bits has to be rounded to the available precision, that is 52 bits after the leading 1 of significand for double precision and 63 bits for long double (at least on x86). 1.12 is 112/100 = 28/25. 1/25 is not reprsentable in base 2, 1/5 being the infinite bit serie 0.00110011001100110011.....

Comment: So when you init `long double x = 1.12`, what the compiler does is initilaize the long double with 112/100 rounded to long double precision. It's not the same as writing `long double x = (double) 1.12;` in which case the long double will have same bits as the double - additional 11 trailing bits will be zero.

Comment: BTW, *so different* is a bit more than 1.0e-16, that's really tiny! Consider that the last bit of 1.12 represent a quantum of 2^-52, that's about 2.2e-16, so the representation error of the double is less than 1/2 ulp as due, that's all what you can get with double precision.

Answer (score 1):

> Using exact math, the floating-point value represents ...

`a` is not exactly 1.12 as 0.12 is not [dyadic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational).

```
// `a` not exactly 1.12 
double a = 1.12;  // 1.1200000000000001 * 2^0
```

Nearby `double` values:

```
1.11999999999999988...  Next closest double
1.12                    Code
1.12000000000000011...  Closest double
1.12000000000000033...
```

---

Instead, let us look closer to truer values.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>

int main() {
  double a = 1.12;  // 1.1200000000000001 * 2^0
  double b = 1024LL * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;  // 1 * 2^50
  int prec = DBL_DECIMAL_DIG;
  printf("a %.*e\n", prec, a);
  printf("b %.*e\n", prec, b);

  double c = a * b;
  double whole;
  printf("c %.*e (r:%g)\n", prec, c, modf(c, &whole));
  long long d = (long long) c;
  printf("d %lld\n", d);
}
```

Output

```
a 1.12000000000000011e+00
b 1.12589990684262400e+15
c 1.26100789566373900e+15 (r:0)
d 1261007895663739
```